# any suggestions with django-chunked-upload and jQuery-File-Upload to upload large files

Tags: jquery, python, django, file-upload

A few days ago the library download `django-chunked-upload` to upload large files into several pieces with Django and it works.

But I have to put a progress bar for the user to see the process of charging and it seems that is intended to work `jQuery-File-upload` but not how to implement it.

When you download the demo of `django-chunked-upload` is an example but this example does not save data in the database.

**Question**

I need someone to help me with an example of how to upload a large file using `django-chunked-upload` and `jQuery-file-upload` and is saved in the database or tell me a method to upload large files with `Django` with a progress bar.

Answer (score 2):

[django-chunked-upload-demo](https://github.com/juliomalegria/django-chunked-upload-demo) is the example you really need to use [django-chunked-upload](https://github.com/juliomalegria/django-chunked-upload). So the question remains is

> When you download the demo of django-chunked-upload is an example but
>   this example does not save data in the database.

If you see in `MyChunkedUploadCompleteView` in `django-chunked-uplad-demo.demo.views`, and its `on_completion` method.

```
def on_completion(self, uploaded_file, request):
    # Do something with the uploaded file. E.g.:
    # * Store the uploaded file on another model:
    # SomeModel.objects.create(user=request.user, file=uploaded_file)
    # * Pass it as an argument to a function:
    # function_that_process_file(uploaded_file)
    pass
```

In the doc string you can clearly see how to save uploaded file in your model. You need to write your own `on_completion` method like

```
def on_completion(self, uploaded_file, request):
    YourModelClass.objects.create(your_file_field=uploaded_file).save()
```

Comment: Hello friend, the truth is that I am somewhat new to programming with django and this is what I have.